# Woocommerce Rest API - Swift 4

Tags: swift, wordpress, xcode9, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to develop a eCommerce store based on a already existing word press site (nonigifts.com). The site uses Woo Commerce as it's database and I figured it would be best to connect to an already existing database instead of recreating a duplicate database. My question is how to create the connection in swift so that I can call images, descriptions, prices, customer data and all of that to the app from Woo Commerce. Do I have to connect once and request many times. Or do i reconnect every time as a function.

The connection has a rest api consumer and secret key. If you have any additional readings with your response I would like those as well.

Thank you!